# Numeric input field JavaScript custom validation

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I have an input numeric field where I registered all changed events:

- *onchange*
- *onkeydown*
- *onkeyup*
- *onmousedown*
- *onmouseup*

I need to permit inserting only numeric values with these rules:

- Values between 0 and 24
- It is  possible to have decimal values.
- Decimal value must be have only 1 decimal digit.
- Decimal section must be a multiple of 0.5.

I need to immediately replace the old value if the current value is invalid.

So I have to accept, for example, values like these:

- 0
- 0.5
- 12
- 23.5
- 24

I can't accept values like these:

- Hello
- -0,
- -1
- .
- ,,
- .5
- 25
- --2
- ...
- e

I tried to use this code, but it does not cover all cases:

```
function customValidation(value) {
    return /^\d*[.,]?]*[5]{0,1}$/.test(value) && (value === "" || (parseFloat(value) <= 24 && parseFloat(value) >= 0));
}

function eventListner(el) {
    if (customValidation(el.value)) {
        el.oldValue = el.value;
    } else if (el.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        el.value = el.oldValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: So in your RegEx you need to match 1 or more digits followed by an optional decimal symbol and 5?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could benefit from using a "number" input type and just specifying the min, max, and step properties instead of using a RegEx for validity. For example:

```
<input type="number" name="myNumber" id="myNumber" min="0" max="24" step="0.5">
```

Then you can just check the validity with the standard methods available:

```
let myNumberInput = document.getElementById("myNumber");
let myNumberIsValid = myNumberInput.checkValidity();
```

The MDN web docs also has some useful information on their [Constraint validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation) page.

Answer (score 0):

This regex covers all cases:

```
/^(?:(?:\d|1\d|2[0-3])(?:\.[05])?|24(?:\.0)?)$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/KZeVKa/1

Expanded:

```
 ^                    # BOS
 (?:
      (?:                  #    0 - 23.5
           \d 
        |  1 \d 
        |  2 [0-3] 
      )
      (?: \. [05] )?
   |                     # or,
      24                   #    24.0
      (?: \. 0 )?
 )
 $                    # EOS
```